# MyBatis Mapping for fetching List of Custom Record Types in Oracle

Tags: oracle, mybatis

We are stuck with mybatis-mapping where we have to fetch list of Oracle Custom Record Types which is returned by a stored procedure.

Can anybody share sample code/mapping if you have any such cases implemented using mybatis.

Package

```
create or replace
package p1 as
TYPE T1 IS RECORD
(P_OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2(80) ,
p_object_status VARCHAR2(25)) ;
TYPE t2 IS TABLE OF t1 index by BINARY_INTEGER;
procedure data_collection_append(t out t2);
procedure data_collection_extract;
end;
```

Package Structure

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY P1 AS
PROCEDURE DATA_COLLECTION_APPEND(t OUT t2) AS
cursor c1 is select object_name,status from user_objects where rownum = 1;
c c1%rowtype;
i number:=0;
begin
  --t := t2() ;
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into c;
    EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(c.object_name||'==>'||c.status);
    T(I).P_OBJECT_NAME:=C.OBJECT_NAME;
    t(i).p_object_status:=c.status;
    i:=i+1;
  end loop; 
end;
procedure data_collection_extract as
t t2;
begin
  data_collection_append(t);
  for i in t.first..t.last
  LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line(t(i).p_object_name||'==>'||t(i).p_object_status);
  end loop; 
end;
END;
```

Mapping

```
    <select id="getLearnerMap" parameterType="Detail" statementType="CALLABLE">
    DECLARE
        v_custom_record p1.T2;

    BEGIN
        v_custom_record := p1.data_collection_append();
        #{objectName, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=OUT} := v_custom_record.P_OBJECT_NAME;

    END;
</select>
```

POJO

```
 public class Detail {
        String objectName;
        String objectStatus;
         // Getter and Setter Methods
    }
```

Error --> indentified "P_OBJECT_NAME" not defined in T1.

Can anybody provide me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change the mapper as follows

```
<resultMap type="detail" id="myResultMap"  >
        <result property="objectNamee" column="P_OBJECT_NAME" />
        <result property="objectStatus" column="p_object_status" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getLearnerMap" parameterType="spInOut" statementType="CALLABLE">

 {call p1.data_collection_append(#{objList, jdbcType=CURSOR, mode=OUT, resultMap=myResultMap, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet})}

</select>
```

create a type in SpInOut in you domain directory

```
public class SpInOut {

    private Object objList;
   //getter setting follows
}
```

---

Here is a complete simple example

### DB side

Create custom type

```
PACKAGE KP_EMP_PCK AS

  type empType is ref cursor;

END KP_EMP_PCK;
```

Create a stored procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE KPLISTEMP
( empList OUT kp_emp_pck.empType
) AS
BEGIN
  open empList for select empid, fname, lname,address from kpemployee order by fname;
END KPLISTEMP;
```

---

**Java Side**

---

Create domain class

```
public class User {

    private String fName;
    private String company;
    private int age;
    private int salary;
    //getter Setter
```

}

Create domain for SpInOut

```
public class SpInOut {

        private Object empList;
       //getter setting follows
    }
```

Mapper interface

```
public interface EmployeeMapper {

    void getEmployees(SpInOut param);

}
```

Mapper xml file

```
<mapper namespace="com.kp.swasthik.db.oracle.persistence.EmployeeMapper">

    <resultMap type="employee" id="empResultMap"  >
        <id property="empId" column="EMPID" />
        <result property="fName" column="FNAME" />
        <result property="lName" column="LNAME" />
        <result property="address" column="ADDRESS"  />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getEmployees"  statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="spInOut" >
        {call kplistemp(#{empList, jdbcType=CURSOR, mode=OUT, resultMap=empResultMap, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet})}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

And finally the service class

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getEmps() {
        try{
            SpInOut data= new SpInOut();
            mapper.getEmployees(data);
            return (List<Employee>) data.getEmpList();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```