# Call oracle function with MyBatis (Annotation Based)

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, ibatis, mybatis-generator

I need call Oracle Function in MyBatis using Annotations.

My Mapper:

```
@Select("{ CALL #{outParam, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := ORA_FUNC( "
    + "#{pNum1, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},"
    + "#{pNum2, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},"
    + "#{pNum3, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN} )}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@ResultType(Integer.class)
public Integer executeFunction(
    @Param("map") Map<String, Object> carteira);
```

and my call to this signature:

```
Map<String, Object> mapParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mapParameters.put("pNum1", carteira.getUnimedCarteira());
mapParameters.put("pNum2", carteira.getCodCarteira());
mapParameters.put("pNum3", carteira.getDigitoCarteira());
mapper.obterRedeBeneficiario(mapParameters);
return mapParameters.get("outParam").toString();
```

The **outParam** is null and the return of mapper is null too.

Can anyone help-me?

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739636/mybatis-mapping-for-fetching-list-of-custom-record-types-in-oracle/26765161#26765161 added a complete example

Comment: Karthik, this example is for XML based, i try similar in annotation based bit dont work

Comment: Can you let us know what changes you made?

Comment: @KarthikPrasad

The sample in the link not applicate in my case. My problem is in the return of function. In parameters is ok.

In XML Based, call functions work perfect:

`<select statementType="CALLABLE" id="callID" parameterType="java.util.Map">`
`{ CALL #{outParam, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := funcName(`
`#{param1, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},`
`#{param2, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},`
`#{param3, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN}`
`  )}`
`</select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a domain class SpInOut class

```
class SpInOut{

    private String outParam;
    private int pNum1;
    private int pNum2;
    private int pNum3;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

And you can change your maaper as below

```
@Select("{ #{outParam, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} = CALL ORA_FUNC( "
    + "#{pNum1, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},"
    + "#{pNum2, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},"
    + "#{pNum3, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN} )}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
public void executeFunction(
    SpInOut inOut);
```

Comment: Thanks @karthik-prasad, its work. I try using a HashMap and works too:


`@Select("{ CALL #{map.outParam, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=OUT} := ORA_FUNC( "
    + "#{map.pNum1, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},"
    + "#{map.pNum2, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN},"
    + "#{map.pNum3, jdbcType=NUMERIC, mode=IN} )}")
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
@ResultType(Integer.class)
public Integer executeFunction(
    @Param("map") Map<String, Object> carteira);`


Thanks

Comment: How will you do the same in case of calling a procedure with cursor as OUT param? I tired this but not working:` @Select("{ call MV_METADATA.MV_GET_UI_REPORTS_BY_PAGEC(139,00572,'MVP','%', +            "    'DESC',\n" +
            "    '01-01-1900',\n" +
            "    '01-01-3000',\n" +
            "    'All',\n" +
            "    '9202,9201,129,1007',\n" +
            "    #{res, jdbcType=OTHER, mode=OUT})}")
    @Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
    @ResultType(LookUpParams.class)
    void getData(LookUpParams lookUpParams);`